# MailGun smtp URL

Tags: javascript, meteor, mailgun

I have tried everything to get my MailGun smtp url to work with my domain. I have been able to get the sandbox MailGun domain to work but not my own. This is what I think is closest to being correct:

```
smtp://postmaster%40xyz.com.mailgun.org:mypassword@smtp.mailgun.org:587
```

My DNS is verified, however when I try to send an email I get:

```
Invalid login - 535 5.7.0 Mailgun is not loving your login or password
```

Thoughts?

Comment: Try smtps:// instead of smtp://

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It ended up being very simple. I didn't need all of the paramenters that I thought I needed. Solution below:

```
smtp://postmaster%40xyz.com:paswword@smtp.mailgun.org
```

Comment: yes! i wish i had found this sooner!   Worked on my Meteor app (v1.5) using mup  (v1.3.1). Using "smtp" on Port 587.